# How to connect to ceph cluster from java program

Tags: java, linux, ceph

I'm new to Ceph File system. I have setup 2-node ceph cluster and trying to figure out how to connect to it from java. I have read about libcephfs library but I am not getting how to use it and where to find all those classes.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The Java connector for CephFS is available in the source tree if you are building Ceph:

- Configure with `--enable-cephfs-java`

There are also pre-built packages for Debian and other distros. The http://ceph.com/docs page contains information about obtaining the pre-built packages. For Java, just use your distribution's package search tool to look for `ceph` and `java` keywords. On Debian I would install with:

- `apt-get install libcephfs-java`